# how to avoid Code in Datagrip Console while compilation

Tags: datagrip

I am using Datagrip as client for my Postgres, is there a way to disable displaying of code in the console when I compile it, every time I compile code (function/procedure, etc) its displays all the code in the console and compilation result at the end, is there a way to avoid displaying the code on the console.

[ConsoleImage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/21ybQ.png)

Regards
Bharat

Comment: Sorry, this is very unclear. Can you please specify what you mean? Screenshots also help.

Comment: I added an image.

Comment: So you don't want to see queries in the output, right?

Comment: Yes, I don't want to see the code I am compiling in the console, just the final output if the compilation was successful or failure.